# necesito guardar el equipoEmpleado en el viewData

Tags: c#, jquery, html5, asp.net-mvc-5, css-grid-layout

**Necesito guardar en las vistas del edit equipo empleado en el viewdata.**

```
<div class="card-body">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "contact_form", @id = "formEdit" }))
        {



        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.equipoEmpleadoId)




            <input type="hidden" name="idSession" id="idSession" value="@Model.equipoEmpleadoId" />
            <input id="errDupli" name="errDupli" type="hidden" value="@ViewData["Err"]">

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.equipoEmpleadoId, "Equipo", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("equipoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.equipoEmpleadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.equipoEmpleadoId, "Empleado", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("empleadoId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.equipoEmpleadoId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Y luego en el get edit del controlador tengo que guardar idequipo y idempleado y asignar un valor en el viewdata

Comment: Bienvenid@ a StackOverflow, podrias indicar que te falla o donde estas atascad@?

Comment: Hola, edita la pregunta e indica también el o los Modelos y el Controlador con las Acciones Edit..